# How to Get sum / calculate between price and quantity in Ionic 3?

Tags: php, json, ionic3, calculated-columns

I need some help.

How to get Total Price from Price and Quantity like Cart?
i tried from tutorials but not working

transaction.html

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src="http://example.com//picture/souvenir/{{item.photo}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <ion-row>
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      </ion-row>
      <p>QTY
        <input type="number" #quantity
        value="1" style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid #5a5a5a;height: 25px;
        border-radius: 20px;text-align: center;">  <!-- Qty -->
      </p>
      <p #retailPrice>Price :&nbsp;Rp. {{item.price}} </p> <!-- Price -->
      <p><b>Total Price:&nbsp;Rp. {{total}}</b></p> <!--This Total Price-->
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

transaction.ts

```
export class TransactionPage {

  item: any;
  userdata: any = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
  {
    this.item = this.navParams.get("item"); 
    this.userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userlogin')) || [];
    console.log(this.userdata);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TransactionPage');
  }
}
```

i need if quantity "5" and price "100" = total price "500"

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngModel` to define which variable will keep the quantity number. After it, you just need to calculate **price * quantity**.

See the documentation to know more: [https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description)

**transaction.html**

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src="http://example.com//picture/souvenir/{{item.photo}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <ion-row>
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      </ion-row>
      <p>QTY
        <input [(ngModel)]="quantity" type="number" #quantity
        value="1" style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid #5a5a5a;height: 25px;
        border-radius: 20px;text-align: center;">  <!-- Qty -->
      </p>
      <p #retailPrice>Price :&nbsp;Rp. {{item.price}} </p> <!-- Price -->
      <p><b>Total Price:&nbsp;Rp. {{item.price * quantity}}</b></p> <!--This Total Price-->
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**transaction.ts**

```
export class TransactionPage {

  item: any;
  userdata: any = [];

  quantity = 0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
  {
    this.item = this.navParams.get("item"); 
    this.userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userlogin')) || [];
    console.log(this.userdata);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TransactionPage');
  }
}
```

Comment: you must change ```item.quantity``` for your quantity variable.

Comment: how about that?... im sorry cause im beginner in ionic .. :)

Comment: don't worry. what's your quantity variable name?

Comment: so put this attribute inside your ion-input ```[(ngModel)]="quantity"``` and inside your page.ts, create the variable quantity. ```var quantity = 0;``` and change ```item.quantity``` to ```quantity```. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Updated. Check it out and read the documentation, it helps you a lot.